# Rotate images with single tap gesture in XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So, I'm working in Xcode 5, OS X Mavericks. I have storyboard with one view in it in my project. Programmatically, I have added about 384 UIImageViews in loop in my view. Here's my code I used for it:

```
-(void)setImageViewsImages {

[self create Randoms]; //it creates random numbers for definition of rotation direction (rn)

for (i = 0; i < 480; i++) {
currentImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
                currentImage.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 20, 20);
               if (rn == 1) {
                    CGAffineTransform imageRotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
                    currentImage.transform = imageRotation;

                } else {
                    switch (rn) {

                        case 2: {
                            CGAffineTransform imageRotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.5);
                            currentImage.transform = imageRotation;
                        }
                            break;

                        case 3: {
                            CGAffineTransform imageRotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
                            currentImage.transform = imageRotation;
                        }
                            break;

                        case 4: {
                            CGAffineTransform imageRotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 1.5);
                            currentImage.transform = imageRotation;
                        }
                            break;
                    }

                }

[self.view addSubview:currentImage];

                x = x + 20;

                if (x == 320) {
                    x = 0;
                    y = y + 20;
                }


            }
}
```

So, what my question is: I want to add a single tap gesture recognizer onto each created image, and then, when all images are in their places, I want to have opportunity to rotate each image right (or left, it doesn't matter) with single tap on it. I wrote this code, and put it in my loop just before `[self.view addSubview:currentImage];`, :

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                            action:@selector(didSingleTap:)];
                singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
                [currentImage addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

but I can't understand, where to go further.

Thanks for help in advance and sorry for my bad English, hope you will be able to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the only link you're now missing is an access to the imageView instance from the `didSingleTap:`. The right way IMO would be subclassing `UIImageView`, instantiate your subclasses instead and when adding the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to it calling a method in the subclass instance. Most proper approach would be to delegate the callback back to your view controller like so:

.h

```
@class RotatingImageView;

@protocol RotatingImageViewDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void) rotatingImageViewWasTapped:(RotatingImageView*) rotatingImageView;
@end

@interface RotatingImageView : UIImageView
@property (nonatomic,weak) id<RotatingImageViewDelegate> delegate;
-(void) onTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*) sender;
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation RotatingImageView

- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    self = [super initWithImage:image];
    if (self) {
        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onTap:)];
        singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)onTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    [self.delegate rotatingImageViewWasTapped:self];
}
@end
```

your view controller would then implement the `RotatingImageViewDelegate` protocol, assign itself as a delegate of each `RotatingImageView` instance and on each tap it would receive the `rotatingViewWasTapped:` callback with the appropriate image view in the parameter. You could either do the logic directly in the `onTap:` method inside the subclass or handle it in your view controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And where in .m file I need to put your .m code? When I'm trying to paste it all just before "@implementation ViewController", XCode tells me: "@synthesize of 'weak' property is only allowed in ARC or GC mode"

Comment: You can paste this as you said in your viewcontroller's .h and .m, but I would suggest creating new files for this class for better project organization. In case you're not using ARC, switch the `weak` property type to `assign`. But BTW in that case you also have pending retains on every created image view and gesture recognizer - don't forget to release them at the end of each loop. ;)

Comment: When I'm trying to add your code in my .h and .m files, XCode doesn't show any errors, application runs on simulator, but when I tap on one or another image, the image doesn't rotate

Comment: Hi, I didn't add any code for rotation of the image view. Just add it to your view controller's `rotatingImageViewWasTapped:` method. If nothing happens test if this code gets executed (by breakpoints or logs.) Don't forget to change the type of the image views to the new class and assign your view controller as delegate to each of them.

Comment: I am new in coding for iOS, so I understand not all the things you've said :( Can I please send you my .m and .h files by e-mail for you to show me what to do with my code?

Comment: does your `rotatingImageViewWasTapped:` get called?

Comment: No, it doesn't, I can't understand, what to do

Comment: Hello again. Now I can understand, what you meaned in your answer, but the code doesn't get called

Comment: Everything should get executed provided you set the view controller as the delegate (best right after the initialization of each RotatingImageView).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you recreating the logic of a `UICollectionView`?

You stated you are on mavericks so iOS 5 support is not an issue.

My advice would be to create a `UICollectionViewController`, use the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` with a itemSize of `20, 20` and create a custom cell.

In the setSelected method, transform the image as such:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected;
{
  [super setSelected:selected];
  self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((arc4random() % 4) * M_PI);
}
```